# Is this Spanish sentence grammatically incorrect? "Me importas todos ustedes"

Tags: gramática, verbos, sustantivos

I saw the following phrase in a Spanish 1 poster I am interested in purchasing but I came across this Spanish sentence

> Me importas todos ustedes

I believe this sentence is grammatically incorrect for the following reason, the subject **me** does not seem to agree with the verb **importas**.  Please help.

Comment: Probably it's just a typo. As pointed by Steve Butler, the correct verb form is: importan. Notice that the subject in your sentence is "todos ustedes" and not the first person, that is omitted in Spanish: I. You may see it more clearly if I reorder a bit the original sentence: Todos ustedes me importan.

Answer (score 7):

I believe that the verb *importar* is used similar to other reflexive verbs. Specifically *gustar*.

If you like something you say "me gusta" instead of "me gusto", because it's the thing you like.

If there is an error, I would say it should be **importan**, not *importas*, since you're using "ustedes" not "tú" as subject.

> Me **importan** todos ustedes

It's 'you all' that I care about. But my knowledge of Spanish is fairly elementary and I am probably wrong.

https://studyspanish.com/grammar/lessons/gustar

Comment: That's right, "todos ustedes" is the subject and it should be "importan". "Importar" means "to matter", so this verb works just like the English equivalent does.

Comment: In some Andalusian regions, specially around the Cádiz area, it would also be valid to say "me importáis todos ustedes", as in that region the word "ustedes" is used as "vosotros". But this is a very specific case, this answer by Steve Butler is actually the right one.

Comment: @Charlie but that is a good point since it gives a second alternative for the kind of typo. One is that "s" changes by "n" or two is that there is an "i" missing before the "s".

Answer (score 0):

It is gramatically incorrect as the subject of the sentence is `todos ustedes`, that is, third person, plural. On the other hand, the verb is conjugated in the second person, singular.